# In MVVM + Coordinator, how to deal with sub view?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm working on an iOS MVVM + Coordinator/ RxSwift project (non swiftUI).

In the groundViewController, there are multiple items on the screen, and the user can tap on any item to call a detailed view of that item. The detailed view will slide in after tapping on an item, and when the user taps another item, the detailed view will sliding out then sliding in again with updated info. detailedView is half screen size, user can also tap on empty space on groundViewController to dismiss the detailed view (sliding out animation).(So there will be only one detailedView)

I decided to make that detailed view as an UIView, which will have its own coordinator and ViewModel and be added to groundViewControll.view. But I'm now confused about how to communicate between them or event flow.

Question: In MVVM/Coordinator pattern, is it correct to make this flow as:

```
groundViewController (receive a tap on the object) - > 
groundViewModel - >
groundCoordinator (creat and pass itemID ) - > 
detailedViewCoordinator (creat) - > 
detailedViewModel and detialedView
```

And who should in charge of detialedView's sliding in/out animation?

Comment: GroundCoordinator should be in charge of showing detail and dismissing it. You should pass the route of the coordinator to the detailView, which triggers another detail but closes the current detail first.

Comment: So when the detail view is visible, you can still see and interact with the items on the ground view?

Comment: @DanielT. You are correct. That's one of the reasons I choose UIView instead of UIViewController. I just updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the ground view receives the tap, it tells the ground view model.

1. The ground view model tells the ground coordinator.
2. The ground coordinator tells the current detail coordinator (if there is one) to dismiss.
3. The current detail coordinator dismisses its view.
4. The ground coordinator creates a new detail coordinator.
5. The ground coordinator tells the new detail coordinator to present.
6. The new detail coordinator creates a detail view model and detail
   view. It passes the detail view model to the detail view.
7. The detail coordinator presents the detail view.

There are some variations in exactly when items are created and destroyed, but the above is the general idea.

Comment: And who should in charge of /trigger detialedView's sliding in/out animation?

Comment: The detail coordinator triggers it, the view controller performs it.